# Leaflet.js time slider/animation with Mapbox TileLayers

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I've got a RESTful API pushing .png-based TileLayers and associated metadata (datetime, lat/lon, etc.)

I'd like to create a time slider or animation to display them as per the user's inputs.

What is a good starting point? I'm seeing some libraries which do not seem to have support for TileLayers/raster overlays. Can anyone recommend a better choice?

Comment: This may be useful: https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback - Example 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After perusing the literature, this is the solution I chose to start from:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/260hffor/

We basically build an array of tile layer strings and then use a slider to load them dynamically.

`.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {{GET ROUTE GOES HERE}},
            success: function (data) {
                imageLayers = [];
                $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                    imageLayers.push(L.tileLayer(mbUrl, { id: {{TILE LAYER ID GOES HERE}}, token: {{TOKEN GOES HERE}}, format: 'png', time: {{IMAGE 
 DATE TIME GOES HERE}}.substr(0, 10)}))
                });
                map.setView([data[0].{{LATITUDE PROPERTY}}, data[0].{{LONGITUDE PROPERTY}}], 14);
                layerGroup = L.layerGroup(imageLayers);
                var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
                    layer: layerGroup,
                    follow: null
                });
                map.addControl(sliderControl);
                sliderControl.startSlider();
                $('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 10));`